# Python 2.7 inheritance - can i wrap overriden mehods without changing child code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, descriptor

I have the following code classes:

```
Class Parent:
  def func(self):
    pass
    

Class ChildA(Parent):
  def func(self):
    <ChildA Func Implementation>

Class ChildA(Parent):
  def func(self):
    <ChildB Func Implementation>
```

Is there a way to "wrap" every implementation of "func", to make it behave as follows:

```
def func(self):
   with send_metrics:
      <ChildA Func Implementation>
```

**without changing any of the child classes code?**

I have looked into creating a descriptor for the parent class, but in order for that to work i need to change every child class to also use this descriptor. i'm trying to avoid it as there can be a ton of child classes. - i saw that it's possible to do somehting similar in Python 3.7, but i'm working with 2.7

I'll note that i can't change the actual interface, meaning - a 3rd party scheduler calls "func", and I can't make it call a different method.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you gather together instances of these child classes in order to send them to the scheduler? You should be able to make a wrapper that has a child as an attribute.

Comment: @quamrana i'm not controlling the scheduler code, from which it takes tasks & runs them.